# Outlets are being hidden on dismiss of view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, outlet, dismissviewcontroller

In my app, I have a screen it is like a submit form, which contains dropdown picker, textfields and buttons. There are two buttons one is to pick image from gallery and other one to pick image from camera. My problem is after filling all the textfields, I am picking an image from gallery and after dismiss from the presented gallery screen. All my outlets are not visible it means become transparent. This occurs only in iOS 12 version but in iOS 11 version it is working fine. Please help.
 My screen as below.

**Before uploading image**

[image: before uploading image]

**After uploading image**

[image: After uploading image it looks as below.]

Coding language is objective C.

My outlets are as below.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtSubmit;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtVisitDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCalimType;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtInvoiceAmount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtServiceProvoider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtReceiptsNo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *btnSnapClick; //weak
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCameraclick; //weak
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *mediaPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnUpload;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *CollectionContanst; //weak
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSubmitWithRadious; //weak
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton; //weak
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

My dismiss code is as below.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I got error when i try to view in View debugger, as below.

> Error:    Unable to capture view hierarchy. Details:  Log Title: Data
>   source expression execution failure. Log Details: (null)
>
> Log Method: -[DBGDataSourceConnectionLibViewDebugger
>   _executeLLDBExpression:forRequest:onPotentialThread:iteration:]_block_invoke_2
>   Method:   -[DBGViewDebugger updateDebugHierarchy]_block_invoke_2
>   Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning
>   message and any useful information you can provide. 2018-11-16
>   15:12:32.872415+0530 NTUCAdeptCliniFlex[213:3848] Error:
>   DebugHierarchyRequest - Failed to unarchive request data with error:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Even though the screen is blank, when i click somewhere it is displaying as below.

**when i clicked somewhere on the screen**

[image: when i clicked somewhere on the screen]

Xcode 9.2

```
- (void)zcImagePickerController:(ZCImagePickerController *)imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info {

    BOOL isValidImage = YES;
    [self dismissPickerView];

    for (NSDictionary *imageDic in info) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imageDic objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        NSData  *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.4);
        double imgLength = (imageData.length);
        double imgLengthKb = imgLength/1024;
        if(imgLengthKb <= maxFileSize){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //update your UI stuff here.
                NSString *base64 = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
                int randomID = arc4random() % 900000 + 100000;
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd_MM_yyyy"];
                [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
                NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
                NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];
                NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%d%@", @"ios_upload_",dateString,@"_",randomID,@".jpg"];
                NSDictionary *dictContact =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:base64,@"File64ByteStream",fileName,@"FileName", nil];
                [_imageViewArray addObject:dictContact];
                self.CollectionContanst.constant=128; //128
            });
        }else{
            isValidImage = NO;
        }
    }
    [_collectionView reloadData];
//    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//        [_collectionView reloadData];
//    });
    if(isValidImage  == NO){
        [self showAlertonImage];
    }
}

- (void)dismissPickerView {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The above code is used to pick image from gallery.

Even i used view hierarchy debugger, it looks blank. Please check the below attachment
[This image is from view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ86e.png)

Comment: Check you viewWillAppear/Disappear methods. Do you do something there?

Comment: i think there is nothing wrong with outlets but with rendering after return show you viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear if you used

Comment: Earlier i had the same doubt. I commented both viewWillAppear & viewDidAppear.

Comment: @Shaik Arshad outlets generally need to be a weak reference as they will already be referenced from the view, and the controller owns the view. Anyhow, the issue you are facing is not related to outlets I guess. Please try using the view debugger option to see if the components are present in the view hierarchy and only the frame is changed due to some constraints issue.

Comment: @GoGreen sorry for late reply as i already mentioned that it is working fine in iOS 11 and below versions, the problem occur only with iOS 12. Even the outlets are not visible, when i click on the screen, what ever the code is return it is working like., on click of upload receipt button, it is opening gallery. The only problem is the outlets are not visible. That too it is not occurring every time, this problem comes only for the first time, from second time when i come to that screen all the outlets are visible.

Comment: Hi @Shaik. Im not able to understand what you meant by "outlets are not visible". Can you try using the [view debugger](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1879-view-debugging-in-xcode-6) option and see if it is an autolayout contraints issue?

Comment: @GoGreen please check my question, i have updated. I cannot able to get the view hierarchy.

Comment: @Shaik Please give details about code on how you are picking image from gallery and any additional code you do before dismissing the gallery controller. It can occur if you are trying to set wrong values to view attributes.

Comment: @GoGreen please check i added picking image from gallery code

Comment: @GoGreen even it looks blank in view hierarchy. Please find the screen shot from above.

Comment: @ShaikArshad you can check the outlines of the view or the entire heirarchy is displayed at the top. What I meant is to check if the object is present in this heirarchy. Visually it might be blank due to wrong frames.

Comment: @ShaikArshad please go through this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1879-view-debugging-in-xcode-6) for more insight.